# On subversion hooks, how the post commit template is getting generated inside hooks folder?

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

Some post-commit tmpl uses `commit-email.pl` while others use `mailer.py` by default. Could you tell me how this works?

Comment: they call these external tools?!

Comment: Whenever we create a repository, a post commit template is generated but in some post commit templates  commitemail.pl is used while in others mailer.py is used. I dont understand why.

Comment: Because author of hook want to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will give it a try. The following is happening when you create a new Subversion repository (of course depending on the tool and version you are using, that may be different)

1. The server administrator starts in the shell the command `svnadmin create <repo-name>`.
2. Depending on the infrastructure (Apache, svnserve, ...) the administrator has to add configuration to the middleware, so that repository may be accessed.
3. As part of that creation, the directory `hooks` was created, with the default entries of Subversion. These have all the suffix `.tmpl` which means that none of the hooks is active by default.
4. By renaming the hook files to the real name ( `pre-commit` instead of `pre-commit.tmpl`), the hook is activated in will be used by Subversion.

So it is the decision of the administrator which hook to use (if any), Subversion provides only examples or default implementations that may be activated by the administrator.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html with the section "Implementing Repository Hooks" for details.

Comment: got it, Thank you so much!

Comment: So accept the answer (and give me some addtional thumbs up, please :-)